# What is the longest known vanity address generated?

Tags: wallet, address, vanity-address, tools

Anyone can generate a [vanity address](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=25804.0) of arbitrary length with appropriate tools, it's just a matter of performing enough computations. What is the longest known vanity address anyone has generated?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's impossible to say for sure what's a vanity address and what's generated purely at random, but [1CFBdvaiZgZPTZERqnezAtDQJuGHKoHSzg](http://blockexplorer.com/address/1CFBdvaiZgZPTZERqnezAtDQJuGHKoHSzg) is 34 characters with no digits in it other than the initial '1'.  That may well be a vanity address.  Then again on average [1 in every 515](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fpow%28%2848.0%2F58%29%2C33%29jjjj) 34-character addresses you generate won't have any digits in them other than the leading 1, so possibly not.

The address with the longest initial list of lower-case letters is [1yaniraswqyghuJKCRrGwJUA2HakWtRad](http://blockexplorer.com/address/1yaniraswqyghuJKCRrGwJUA2HakWtRad), and is clearly a vanity address since it appears in the [same transaction](http://blockexplorer.com/tx/751ff11286a43da5d6cf7da8f5bc736e522bbd698ec03c76c63368e5260667e6#o175) as many other vanity addresses.

**Edit:** I just found this one:

```
1QBDLYTDFHHZAABYSKGKPWKLSXZWCCJQBX
```

It belongs to etotheipi, author of the [Armory Bitcoin Client](http://bitcoinarmory.com/), and was found using vanitygen, as he said in a [bitcointalk forum post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=64449.msg809780#msg809780):

> Yessir!  I got a little crazy with vanitygen and succeeded.  It
>   should've taken about 70 days of computation time but I got lucky and
>   found it in about a week...  (notice no digits either, only uppercase
>   letters).
>
> Unfortunately, it's so cool that people don't even recognize it as a
>   Bitcoin address :)

Comment: My client just generated this address `1NCEERKDRMZD7LbkRYe3FPXDqridjbWxHe` which has a 11 caps in the beginning.

Answer (score 8):

There's this thread on bitcoin talk:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=90982.0

I personally generated this address: 1**Boyishness**fwHq3wSkCkJ7iafUdjhghfU which is the longest one I'm aware of that's not mixed case. It was generated by feeding oclvanitygen a large number of potential prefixes from a large wordlist.

Comment: If you're accepting multiple addresses, isn't that... cheating? In that sense, the bitcoin address 1QBDLYTDFHHZAABYSKGKPWKLSXZWCCJQBX is the longest vanity address generated.

Comment: Cheating on what rules? The question is too vague; strictly all vanity addresses are the same length.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what vanity address I generated:

**1DETACHABLED**D7hgExqScWngMrxDGtXwcX

This is the real word. All characters in the pattern are uppercase. The length of the pattern is 11 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one we created for our nonprofit. hugpuddle.org 
it took several months for us to find it.
1HuGpUDDLEhvehXE1P6xeudqAHqKfs1BFM

Answer (score 1):

11 meaningful characters at the front:

## `GEnesisReVC`

Full address: `1GEnesisReVCQG641yERVQgStUvqH6S9U2`

The memorable part: `1GEnesisReVC...U2`

⛓ [blockchain.info](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1GEnesisReVCQG641yERVQgStUvqH6S9U2) block explorer

•••••

On Mac Pro with GPU it was 9 days to have 50% chance of `genesisre` *(not case sensitive, without VC)*

Was using https://github.com/exploitagency/vanitygen-plus

What I really like about this address:

- capitalization of `GEnesisRe`
- `VC` suffix
- memorable `U2` ending
- capitalization right after `VC`
- capitalization just before `U2`

> OK, so right now time to raise some money and open a VC fund investing in regenerative communities - independent food, energy, water production and focus on education and new post-scarcity paradigm economy.

---

**EDIT / UPDATE:** Out of curiosity tried running the command as if I was to bruteforce it with the exact capitalisation:

```
Difficulty: 9883693997182075238
[20.44 Mkey/s][total 398458880][Prob 0.0%][50% in 10630.3y]
```

With `-i` (case insensitive):

```
Difficulty: 18982355007608803
[19.72 Mkey/s][total 230686720][Prob 0.0%][50% in 21.2y]
```

Bottom line - got lucky, incredibly lucky.

---

**EDIT / UPDATE:**

I wanted to send the minimal transaction (546 Satoshis) and be included in the block but they happened almost instantly, what a chance!

`Don't trust, verify. Happy Bitcoin halving! Monday 11th May 2020`

`Gyf//ybT1XGwV6sOhZf0yCFn1QLmGoD+x/K3x2L+kaqBfKpM8wQb30/8wW3DUT6AQkZUiKIXMfgafQx3cT7e658=`

[image]

## I'm Craig Wright, definitely not a fraud.

Answer (score 0):

"Then again on average 1 in every 515 34-character addresses you generate won't have any digits in them other than the leading 1"

I think it's 1 in every 261    34 char BTC addresses. It's because there are only 9 numbers available (0 not base 58 conform):
(58/49)³³ = 261.007...

One can create easily long vanity addresses like someone did with this one:
1FuckYouFuckYouFuckYouFuckYouz76RT
However, the creator cannot create the priv key so money send to those addresses aren't spendable.

Some other Bitcoin-Vanity addresses:

- 1LitecoiniwdBzUR84opxNeDggcTxHZwC
- 1RiPPLESiHh1vAKf2vfZDJfDQJ73UZpNb
- 1MoNEro159num18KshmWozz7bzW3cZaH5y
- 1steLLarZSNHpMG2JeJx2LoyDQJHDY6RC
- 1Zcash1bw9DNTbDkqaB67uYme44eEmtp6
- 1Dash1Fu4orcgsJKFozDJiDy2b1bub2Qdx
- 1EtherC5LahniSffzNqKKjT6DNiqcyaTFe

How to explain a newcomer that these are Bitcoin addresses ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Check out this one.

1YouTakeRiskWhenUseBitcoin11cGozM

It is an actual wallet, check in an explorer.

Comment: A vanity address is a special address that someone can use. To that end, you must generate a multitude of private keys and then check whether the corresponding address matches the pattern you seek. It is much easier to just make up an address and calculate the appropriate checksum which is what likely happened here (it's too long to find otherwise). In that case the user that created the address does not have the corresponding private key. This is called a _burn address_. I'd only call an address someone can spend from a vanity addresses.

Comment: It's not possible for it to be a spendable address, otherwise the hash used by bitcoin address would be insecure.

Comment: Unless there is a transaction spending from that address, I doubt it's been properly generated. You can easily generate vanity-like addresses using sites like https://gobittest.appspot.com/ProofOfBurn , but you won't get the corresponding private key.