# What is the longest firstbits?

Tags: vanitygen, firstbits

What is the longest used firstbits? How could I find out? I think it would be two vanity addresses with the same prefix, yes? Anything longer than about seven characters for a firstbits would require a lot of computation.

Comment: No easy way to find [the shortest](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7466/how-to-find-the-shortest-unused-firstbits), so it's not clear why you expect there was an easy way to find the longest, instead.

Comment: @Lohoris The largest problem is that if you say "the longest firstbits is `1aaaaaaaaaaa`" then somebody with vanitygen will just try to make two vanity addresses that have more characters in common.

Comment: @NickODell: Unless the longest firstbits is already so long that finding a longer one will be computationally prohibitive.

Comment: Finding the shortest one unused is rather different than finding the longest one used, IMO.

Comment: It is valid (see http://uncaptcha.net/bitcoin.php ), but I think nobody has the private key...
Chance to choice valid address is 1 : 4 billions which is no computational problem...

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3730/5406

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the one with the longest firstbits
http://blockchain.info/fb/1234567891234567891234567891w

Comment: "Sorry this is is not a valid bitcoin address"